# Intellij Error : Internal Error Cannot Run Program in Directory Java Play Angular

Tags: java, angularjs, intellij-idea, playframework

I've created a new play java app and imported it to intellij.

my default sdk is java 1.8

IDE intellij 14.1

On running the application i get the below error.

```
    Error:Internal error: (java.io.IOException) Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java" (in directory "/media/seroney/Stuff/Projects/Java/Play+FrameWork/Angularjs/blogapp/server"): error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java" (in directory "/media/seroney/Stuff/Projects/Java/Play+FrameWork/Angularjs/blogapp/server"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at com.intellij.scala.play.jpsSupport.Play2TemplateJpsBuilder$$anonfun$build$1.apply(Play2TemplateJpsBuilder.scala:193)
    at com.intellij.scala.play.jpsSupport.Play2TemplateJpsBuilder$$anonfun$build$1.apply(Play2TemplateJpsBuilder.scala:133)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at com.intellij.scala.play.jpsSupport.Play2TemplateJpsBuilder.build(Play2TemplateJpsBuilder.scala:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1196)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:877)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:945)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:840)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:663)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:370)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:191)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:293)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:242)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intellij IDEA is unable to find the Java Path specified. Correct this in intellij Config.

Comment: Please give more details. Intellij has lots of Configs

Comment: https://samirbehara.com/2018/01/03/intellij-idea-error-cannot-run-program-no-such-file-or-directory/